# Receiving No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, with an axios get request

Tags: cors, axios

I'm using the request below:

```
axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=43.2502078,13.513169&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=MYKEY',{headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}})
.then(response => this.setState({restaurantsFetchedFromGoogle:response.data}));
```

but I'm still receiving the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` on my console. The url is working correctly as it fetche's the results when using Postman. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by `npm install cors --save`, removing `{headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}}` and re-running the localserver